# Docx4J not working on Websphere Liberty Server 24.0.0.2

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, websphere-liberty, docx4j

We are using Docx4J ver 8 to convert docx file to pdf using the Eclipselink MOXy library. Java version that we are using is Java 21. It works perfectly on Tomcat 10 server but same does not work on Websphere Liberty 24 server. We are getting the following exception related to JAXB Context.

```
    2024-03-14T11:17:45.813+04:00 DEBUG 23604 --- [cutor-thread-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/compiler/Generator.generateSchemaFiles(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/util/Map; @89: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/eclipse/persistence/core/sessions/CoreProject'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @89
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/compiler/Generator', 'java/lang/String', 'java/util/Map', 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject', 'org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/XMLContext', 'org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/XMLMarshaller' }
    stack: { 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject', 'java/lang/Class' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a2c 2ab4 002c b700 c22a b400 312a b400
    0000010: 2cb6 0093 2ab4 002c b600 972a b400 2cb6
    0000020: 009a 2ab4 002c b600 9d2a b400 2cb6 00a0
    0000030: 2ab4 002c b600 8db6 00b7 bb00 c659 b700
    0000040: c84e bb00 c959 2dc0 00cb b700 cd3a 0419
    0000050: 04b6 00d0 3a05 2d12 d4b6 00d6 c000 dc3a
    0000060: 062a b400 31b6 00ba 3a07 1907 b900 de01
    0000070: 003a 09a7 005e 1909 b900 e401 00c0 00d4
    0000080: 3a08 bb00 ea59 bb00 ec59 2bb8 00ee b700
    0000090: f212 f4b6 00f6 1908 b600 fab6 00f6 b600
    00000a0: feb7 0101 3a0a 1908 b601 023a 0b19 0b13
    00000b0: 0106 1301 08b6 010a 1906 190b b901 1002
    00000c0: 0019 0519 08bb 0114 5919 0ab7 0116 b601
    00000d0: 1919 09b9 011f 0100 9aff 9e2a b400 31b6
    00000e0: 0122 b0
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@118,{Object[#1],Object[#107],Object[#81],Object[#215],Object[#201],Object[#282],Object[#220],Object[#223],Top,Object[#229]},{})
    same_frame_extended(@209)
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch:1,104'
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/compiler/Generator.generateSchemaFiles(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/util/Map; @89: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/eclipse/persistence/core/sessions/CoreProject'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @89
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/compiler/Generator', 'java/lang/String', 'java/util/Map', 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject', 'org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/XMLContext', 'org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/XMLMarshaller' }
    stack: { 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject', 'java/lang/Class' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a2c 2ab4 002c b700 c22a b400 312a b400
    0000010: 2cb6 0093 2ab4 002c b600 972a b400 2cb6
    0000020: 009a 2ab4 002c b600 9d2a b400 2cb6 00a0
    0000030: 2ab4 002c b600 8db6 00b7 bb00 c659 b700
    0000040: c84e bb00 c959 2dc0 00cb b700 cd3a 0419
    0000050: 04b6 00d0 3a05 2d12 d4b6 00d6 c000 dc3a
    0000060: 062a b400 31b6 00ba 3a07 1907 b900 de01
    0000070: 003a 09a7 005e 1909 b900 e401 00c0 00d4
    0000080: 3a08 bb00 ea59 bb00 ec59 2bb8 00ee b700
    0000090: f212 f4b6 00f6 1908 b600 fab6 00f6 b600
    00000a0: feb7 0101 3a0a 1908 b601 023a 0b19 0b13
    00000b0: 0106 1301 08b6 010a 1906 190b b901 1002
    00000c0: 0019 0519 08bb 0114 5919 0ab7 0116 b601
    00000d0: 1919 09b9 011f 0100 9aff 9e2a b400 31b6
    00000e0: 0122 b0
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@118,{Object[#1],Object[#107],Object[#81],Object[#215],Object[#201],Object[#282],Object[#220],Object[#223],Top,Object[#229]},{})
    same_frame_extended(@209)

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:527)
        at [internal classes]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614)
        at [internal classes]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:203)
        at [internal classes]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:203)
        at [internal classes]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:124)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:203)
        at [internal classes]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:203)
        at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/compiler/Generator.generateSchemaFiles(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/util/Map; @89: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/eclipse/persistence/core/sessions/CoreProject'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @89
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/compiler/Generator', 'java/lang/String', 'java/util/Map', 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject', 'org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/XMLContext', 'org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/XMLMarshaller' }
    stack: { 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject', 'java/lang/Class' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a2c 2ab4 002c b700 c22a b400 312a b400
    0000010: 2cb6 0093 2ab4 002c b600 972a b400 2cb6
    0000020: 009a 2ab4 002c b600 9d2a b400 2cb6 00a0
    0000030: 2ab4 002c b600 8db6 00b7 bb00 c659 b700
    0000040: c84e bb00 c959 2dc0 00cb b700 cd3a 0419
    0000050: 04b6 00d0 3a05 2d12 d4b6 00d6 c000 dc3a
    0000060: 062a b400 31b6 00ba 3a07 1907 b900 de01
    0000070: 003a 09a7 005e 1909 b900 e401 00c0 00d4
    0000080: 3a08 bb00 ea59 bb00 ec59 2bb8 00ee b700
    0000090: f212 f4b6 00f6 1908 b600 fab6 00f6 b600
    00000a0: feb7 0101 3a0a 1908 b601 023a 0b19 0b13
    00000b0: 0106 1301 08b6 010a 1906 190b b901 1002
    00000c0: 0019 0519 08bb 0114 5919 0ab7 0116 b601
    00000d0: 1919 09b9 011f 0100 9aff 9e2a b400 31b6
    00000e0: 0122 b0
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@118,{Object[#1],Object[#107],Object[#81],Object[#215],Object[#201],Object[#282],Object[#220],Object[#223],Top,Object[#229]},{})
    same_frame_extended(@209)

        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$ContextPathInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:994)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$ContextPathInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:922)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:131)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:217)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:175)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:336)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:508)
        at org.docx4j.jaxb.Context.<clinit>(Context.java:120)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:814)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Load3.get(Load3.java:146)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:561)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:410)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:376)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:341)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.load(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:180)
        at com.expleo.rtftopdf.ApplicationController.docxToPDF(ApplicationController.java:494)
        at com.expleo.rtftopdf.ApplicationController.replaceTextDocx(ApplicationController.java:473)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:262)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:917)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:829)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
        ... 26 more

2024-03-14T11:17:46.601+04:00 ERROR 23604 --- [cutor-thread-10] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/convertdocx/2] due to exception [Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/compiler/Generator.generateSchemaFiles(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/util/Map; @89: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/eclipse/persistence/core/sessions/CoreProject'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @89
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/compiler/Generator', 'java/lang/String', 'java/util/Map', 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject', 'org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/XMLContext', 'org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/XMLMarshaller' }
    stack: { 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject', 'java/lang/Class' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a2c 2ab4 002c b700 c22a b400 312a b400
    0000010: 2cb6 0093 2ab4 002c b600 972a b400 2cb6
    0000020: 009a 2ab4 002c b600 9d2a b400 2cb6 00a0
    0000030: 2ab4 002c b600 8db6 00b7 bb00 c659 b700
    0000040: c84e bb00 c959 2dc0 00cb b700 cd3a 0419
    0000050: 04b6 00d0 3a05 2d12 d4b6 00d6 c000 dc3a
    0000060: 062a b400 31b6 00ba 3a07 1907 b900 de01
    0000070: 003a 09a7 005e 1909 b900 e401 00c0 00d4
    0000080: 3a08 bb00 ea59 bb00 ec59 2bb8 00ee b700
    0000090: f212 f4b6 00f6 1908 b600 fab6 00f6 b600
    00000a0: feb7 0101 3a0a 1908 b601 023a 0b19 0b13
    00000b0: 0106 1301 08b6 010a 1906 190b b901 1002
    00000c0: 0019 0519 08bb 0114 5919 0ab7 0116 b601
    00000d0: 1919 09b9 011f 0100 9aff 9e2a b400 31b6
    00000e0: 0122 b0
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@118,{Object[#1],Object[#107],Object[#81],Object[#215],Object[#201],Object[#282],Object[#220],Object[#223],Top,Object[#229]},{})
    same_frame_extended(@209)
]

java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/compiler/Generator.generateSchemaFiles(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/util/Map; @89: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/eclipse/persistence/core/sessions/CoreProject'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @89
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/compiler/Generator', 'java/lang/String', 'java/util/Map', 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject', 'org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/XMLContext', 'org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/XMLMarshaller' }
    stack: { 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject', 'java/lang/Class' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a2c 2ab4 002c b700 c22a b400 312a b400
    0000010: 2cb6 0093 2ab4 002c b600 972a b400 2cb6
    0000020: 009a 2ab4 002c b600 9d2a b400 2cb6 00a0
    0000030: 2ab4 002c b600 8db6 00b7 bb00 c659 b700
    0000040: c84e bb00 c959 2dc0 00cb b700 cd3a 0419
    0000050: 04b6 00d0 3a05 2d12 d4b6 00d6 c000 dc3a
    0000060: 062a b400 31b6 00ba 3a07 1907 b900 de01
    0000070: 003a 09a7 005e 1909 b900 e401 00c0 00d4
    0000080: 3a08 bb00 ea59 bb00 ec59 2bb8 00ee b700
    0000090: f212 f4b6 00f6 1908 b600 fab6 00f6 b600
    00000a0: feb7 0101 3a0a 1908 b601 023a 0b19 0b13
    00000b0: 0106 1301 08b6 010a 1906 190b b901 1002
    00000c0: 0019 0519 08bb 0114 5919 0ab7 0116 b601
    00000d0: 1919 09b9 011f 0100 9aff 9e2a b400 31b6
    00000e0: 0122 b0
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@118,{Object[#1],Object[#107],Object[#81],Object[#215],Object[#201],Object[#282],Object[#220],Object[#223],Top,Object[#229]},{})
    same_frame_extended(@209)

        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$ContextPathInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:994) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.7.6.jar:na]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$ContextPathInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:922) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.7.6.jar:na]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:205) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.7.6.jar:na]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:131) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.7.6.jar:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:217) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:175) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:336) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:508) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
        at org.docx4j.jaxb.Context.<clinit>(Context.java:120) ~[docx4j-core-8.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:814) ~[docx4j-core-8.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Load3.get(Load3.java:146) ~[docx4j-core-8.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:561) ~[docx4j-core-8.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:410) ~[docx4j-core-8.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:376) ~[docx4j-core-8.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:341) ~[docx4j-core-8.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.load(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:180) ~[docx4j-core-8.0.0.jar:na]
        at com.expleo.rtftopdf.ApplicationController.docxToPDF(ApplicationController.java:494) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.expleo.rtftopdf.ApplicationController.replaceTextDocx(ApplicationController.java:473) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:262) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:917) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:829) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:527) ~[io.openliberty.jakarta.servlet.6.0_1.0.86.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614) ~[io.openliberty.jakarta.servlet.6.0_1.0.86.jar:na]
        at [internal classes]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:203) ~[na:na]
        at [internal classes]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:203) ~[na:na]
        at [internal classes]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:124) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:99) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:203) ~[na:na]
        at [internal classes]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:203) ~[na:na]
        at [internal classes]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
```

These are the dependencies added for Docx4J in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>                
    <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-MOXy</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx4j-export-fo</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx4j-MOXy-JAXBContext</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.6</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the code snippet, issue occurs while loading the file in the WordprocessingLMPackage

```
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(templateInputStream);
                    
     String regex=".*(calibri|cour|arial|times|comic|georgia|impact|LSANS|pala|tahoma|trebuc|verdana|symbol|webdings|wingding).*";
     PhysicalFonts.setRegex(regex);             
     MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
     FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);                
     FOSettings foSettings = Docx4J.createFOSettings();
     foSettings.setWmlPackage(wordMLPackage);
     foSettings.setImageDirPath("C:\\upload\\img");         
     Docx4J.toFO(foSettings, os, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);
```

We have also mentioned the JVM setting to tell the Liberty server which context factory to use at runtime

```
-Djavax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Let us know what we are doing wrong. I know that this is do with the configuration on Liberty server. Please if anybody can help with that, it will be of great help.

Comment: What kind of server feature are you trying to use with this ? Like : `<featureManager><feature>jakartaee-10.0</feature></featureManager>`

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens
These are the feature list we have added to the server -

`<featureManager>
   <feature>webProfile-10.0</feature>
  <feature>servlet-6.0</feature>
  <feature>mail-2.1</feature>
  <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
  <feature>transportSecurity-1.0</feature>
  <feature>mail-2.1</feature>  
    </featureManager>`

Comment: `servlet-6.0` feature is for JakartaEE10 which is incompatible with jaxb-2.3 (which is JavaEE8). I'm a bit curious that it works with tomcat 10 but you should move to jaxb-4 which is JakartaEE10

Comment: Legacy docx4j v8 uses javax.ml.bind  so i guess you want Java EE 8 or Jakarta EE 8.  For current docx4j v11.4.11, it would be <feature>jakartaee-9.1</feature>  since docx4j uses jaxb 3 (as 4 drops some implementation lookup mechanisms).  Since you are on Java 21, recommend you move from docx4j v8 to docx4j v11.4.11